# rdd.saveAsTextFile() no exception handled

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to use `rdd.saveAsTextFile("file path")` to write the rdd content as text file.

There is no exception handled on this method.

Basically i need to catch the exception, if something happens at the time of saving the rdd as text file..

Comment: Wrap your call in a try/catch block?

Comment: when i look at the implementation of saveAsTextFile() there are not throwing any exception.

Comment: The fact that an exception is not thrown specifically in that method call does not mean it cannot occur. Maybe the exception is thrown on another level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try/catch block to catch the exception, even if it is not mentioned on method prototype.

The same thing can be used for all Spark exceptions!